# adding the django polls tutorial app to another app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I made a simple blog and the django polls tutorial. Im trying to get them to work together. When I load a post, the poll associated with it loads, the Vote again works but when I click a choice and then the vote button, it loads the post with the id of the poll id. Im not sure if its my "vote" function in views, my "vote" url, or my template thats messed up? Here is my code:

models.py:

```
# Post class
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def display_mySafeField(self):
        return mark_safe(self.body)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

# Poll for the Post
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


# Choice for the poll
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ### main/index page
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.main', name='index'),

    ### url for the post.html
    url(r'^post/(\d+)', 'blog.views.post'),

    ### polls
    url(r'^polls/(\d+)/results/$', 'blog.views.results'),
    url(r'^polls/(\d+)/vote/$', 'blog.views.vote'),
    url(r'^revote/(\d+)/$', 'blog.views.vote_again'),

)
```

views.py:

```
# main view for the posts
def main(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)

    try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
    except ValueError: page = 1

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    d = dict(posts=posts, user=request.user,
             post_list=posts.object_list, months=mkmonth_lst())

    return render_to_response("list.html", d)

def post(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    try:
        poll = Poll.objects.get(post=post)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        poll = None
    d = dict(post=post, comments=comments, form=CommentForm(), user=request.user,
             months=mkmonth_lst(), poll=poll)
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("post.html", d)


#view to vote on the poll
def vote(request, post_id):
    global choice
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=post_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render_to_response('post.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        p.total_votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        p.voted = True
        p.save()

        choices = list(p.choice_set.all())
        for choice in choices:
            percent = choice.votes*100/p.total_votes
            choice.percentage = percent
            choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog.views.post", args=[post_id    ]))

def vote_again(request, post_pk):
    try:
        p = get_object_or_404(Poll, post_id=post_pk)
    except (KeyError, Poll.DoesNotExist):
        pass
    else:
        p.voted = False
        p.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog.views.post", args=[post_pk]))
```

this is what is happening:

```
post1 - linked to - poll1
post2 - not linked
post3 - linked to - poll2
```

when I vote on poll2 which is linked to post3, it updates the database for poll2 but it reloads post2 instead of post3.

Comment: Could you be any more specific? have you narrowed down at all a range where things might not be working? What have you tried? have you dropped in a debugger `pdb` and walked through your code? you have to help us out a little to help you!

Comment: I'm not really sure of the exact problem you're having here. Also, it doesn't help to load your entire code base.

Comment: I tried passing pk, poll_pk, poll_id, post pk, to the view function, sometimes I get an error, but the rest of the time it works but reloads the post that had the id of the poll.

Comment: @D.A im just trying to learn, I thought that if I put up all my code it would be easier for someone to tell me what im doing wrong. I'm new to pyhton/django and this isn't homework or something im being paid to do. I just want to learn. sorry if I annoyed you.

Comment: Not annoyed, just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML form your action is set to `/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote/`. However, it's looking for the `post.pk` value, not `poll.pk`. It uses that value to reload the page after committing the data. That should be your problem right there.

**EDIT**

```
def vote(request, poll_id):
    global choice
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
       try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])    

    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render_to_response('post.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        p.total_votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        p.voted = True
        p.save()

        choices = list(p.choice_set.all())
        for choice in choices:
            percent = choice.votes*100/p.total_votes
            choice.percentage = percent
            choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog.views.post", args=[ p.post.pk ] )
```

Comment: That's giving me a 404 "No Poll matches the given query" which is all i've been getting other than it loading the post of the poll's id.

Comment: That's because in your `vote()` view you are using the `post_id` to query for a Poll.

Comment: Thank you, im sorry if my original question was ambiguous. I really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: No worries. In the future try to at least narrow down the problem for us. Makes our job easier.